# Стилизация детей в CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Здравтсвуйте. Нужна помощь в вертске flex-блоки таким образом, чтобы все элементы + 1 начиная со второго имели одинаковые стили. То есть у меня есть, например, 15 блоков, нужно чтобы первый блок был белый, второй и третий серый, четвертый и пятый белый, шестой и седьмой снова серый и так далее, что бы стили чередовались по 2 элемента.
Не могу понять как этого добиться с помощью css. Чувтсвую, что нужно использовать nth-child, но какое правило не понимаю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать это можно к примеру так:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: 0;
}


/*стили выше добавлены только для этого примера, в реальном проекте используйте normilize.css\reset.css*/

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}

.child:nth-child(4n+2),
.child:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="child">1</div>
<div class="child">2</div>
<div class="child">3</div>
<div class="child">4</div>
<div class="child">5</div>
<div class="child">6</div>
<div class="child">7</div>
<div class="child">8</div>
<div class="child">9</div>
<div class="child">10</div>
<div class="child">11</div>
<div class="child">12</div>
<div class="child">13</div>
<div class="child">14</div>
<div class="child">15</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дополню предыдущий ответ:

написание `%class%:nth-child(xn+y)`, где x и y - шаг и начальный сдвиг (целые числа), означает, что стиль применится ко всем элементам с классом `%class%`, которые являются x-ым чайлдом своего парента, начиная с y-го. Т.е, если у вас задано `.my_class:nth-child(4n+3)`, то это означает "каждый 4-й чайлд c классом my_class, начиная с чайлда № 3".